# Need to write a custom message on checkout page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart

I'm trying to show a message on check out page where a customer is entering his checkout details.
I want to show the message at the beginning of form.

Answer (score 0):

Editing checkout is not that easy. Here's what I do for adding a message at the top of shipping methods selection, in checkout :

**1/ Create a module**

`app/code/MyModule/Shipping/registration.php`

```php
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'MyModule_Shipping',
    __DIR__
);
```

---

`app/code/MyModule/Shipping/etc/module.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MyModule_Shipping" setup_version="0.1.0"/>
</config>
```

---

**2/ Use layout to overide checkout html file**

`app/code/MyModule/Shipping/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

```xml
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shippingMethodListTemplate" xsi:type="string">MyModule_Shipping/shipping-method-list-template</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

---

**3/ Finally, edit your html file**

Copy `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/shipping-method-list.html` to `app/code/MyModule/Shipping/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-method-item-template.html`.

You can now edit your checkout file.

Beware : it's html file that working with javascript (no PHP here).
If you need to add database info, you will also have to rewrite some javascript files using a `requirejs-config.js` file.